# Reading .sde connection file without Esri softwares?

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase, sdelayer

I would like to be able to read connection properties from an sde file **without** any Esri dependencies such as Arcpy, ArcObjects etc. Is this possible?

Comment: You can with arcobjects.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall just updated my question. I cant use any esri dependencies.

Comment: You can certainly ***read*** it. It's less likely that you'll successfully reverse-engineer it. Decrypting the password will be the sticking point.

Comment: If you have the connection parameters then you should not use .sde. If you don't have the connection parameters, I don't think that you would be able to decrypt the password that is stored in the encrypted .sde file. This was a product of ArcSDE which is an ESRI proprietary software.

Comment: No, the connection file is not "a product of ArcSDE". Connection files were always an ArcObjects-managed entity.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hex dump of an .sde string using a program like HxD shows that most of the connection properties are available. It would be left up to the programmer to reverse engineer the structure. As long as the connection string does not store a password it should be possible.
e.g.
[image: Hex Dump Example]